# having trouble with my code for a program involving user inputs

Tags: python, arrays

Python program to read in the temperatures, as user input, for ten consecutive days in Celsius and store them into an array. The entire array should then be displayed. Next each temperature in the array should be converted to Fahrenheit and the entire array should be again be displayed. The formula for converting Celsius to Fahrenheit is °F = (°C × 1.8) + 32. Finally, the number of cool, warm and hot days should be counted and the number of each type of days should be displayed. You should decide on the thresholds for determining whether a day is cool, warm or hot..

here is my code

```
`import array
arr = array.array("f", []) #empty array
print("Provide the temperatures for 10 consecutive days.")
for i in range(10):
temp_c = int(input("Input celcius temperature. "))
arr.append(temp_c)
temp_f = []
for a in arr:
temp_f.append ((temp_c * 1.8) + 32)
print(temp_f)`
```

I'm getting a error code saying it not not iterable

Comment: Please [edit] your code to show the proper formatting so that we can understand your indentation

Comment: g.anderson i have updated my code

Comment: Strill no indentation to see where your loops are actually happening. My _guess_ is that your `temp` is an `int` and then you try to iterate it (`for c in temp`) . You can't iterate over an int. You need to append all of your temp values to a list, then iterate over the list. `for a in arr: tempf.append(...)` perhaps?

Comment: @G.Anderson  yes im getting the an iterable code at the int function, i am new to python and thought i created the temp_f [].

Answer (score 1):

Your `for c in temp:` should probably be `for c in arr`

```
import array
arr = array.array("f", []) #empty array 

print("Provide the temperatures for 10 consecutive days.") 
temp_f = [] 
for i in range(10): 
    temp = int(input("Input celcius temperature. "))
    arr.append(temp) 
print("Celcius Temperatures: " + str(arr.tolist()))
for c in arr: 
    temp_f.append((c * 1.8) + 32)
print("Farenheit Temepratures: " + str(temp_f))
```

I also added the things your program is suppose to do that you didn't add yet

```
minhot = int(input("Minimum Celcius Temperature for HOT: "))
minwarm = int(input("Minimum Celcius Temperature for WARM: "))
mincool = int(input("Minimum Celcius Temperature for COOL: "))
temptype = []
for temp in temp_f:
    if temp > minhot:
        temptype.append("Hot")
    elif temp > minwarm:
        temptype.append("Warm")
    else:
        temptype.append("Hot")
print(temptype)
```

This code checks all the temperatures to see if they meet the criteria for each category

Comment: i am putting this in now, just wondering the change you said from the c to c in arr why is that?

Comment: You do that because temp is your input and arr is the list of Celsius temperatures. You want to get all the values in arr.

Comment: @dbaby if this answer is acceptable, can you click the check box besides the answer to mark it accepted? That'll give closure to your question and other people with a similar issue will be encouraged to view the answer.